# What kind of JOIN statements would retrieve the correct data from 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, phpmyadmin

I am currently working on a VB.NET project that resembles a school's report system. For the sake of this question, I would like to retrieve data from 3 tables. These are detailed below with their fields...

```
(Table CoursesTakes) | TakeID(Primary),StudentID(Foreign),CourseID(Foreign),TargetGrade

(Table Courses) | CourseID(Primary),CourseName

(Table Reports) | ReportID(Primary),CourseTakeID(Foreign),CurrentGrade,ReportNumber

(Table Students) |  StudentID(Primary),StudentName
```

The diagram below may help...

The current system I have in place requires an input of a particular SID. I can then retrieve the corresponding CID and TargetGrade with a SELECT query of the CT table. Additionally, I can retrieve the CGrade and RNumber fields for each of the student's CTs.

The problem I face is designing the query I will need that can give the corresponding CourseName,CGrade,TargetGrade and RNumber for each of the student's particular courses. I am aware of the inner , right and left joins but applying it to 3 tables is proving to be a challenge. Any advice would be greatly appreciated and I would be open to any questions.

Thank you all.

Comment: What is the issue faced using inner join on tables? Can you let us know what have you tried ?

Comment: What I currently have is 2 seperate inner join statements that give me 2 seperate datasets. 1 contains the coursename and the target grade for the students, whilst the other only contains the currentgrades and reportnumber. The issue I face is finding the correct statement that would give the data from the 4 fields into a single dataset as I have hit a wall with the current system in trying to link the correct coursename, targetgrade, currentgrade and report number into a single dataset.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query or queries you have already come up with.

Comment: The problem is not necessarily with my queries, rather the design of the joins that I need to use in order to retrieve the data from these 4 fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use INNER JOINs to join your tables together on their respective/shared keys. Something like the following:

```
SELECT
    Students.StudentID,
    Students.Studentname,
    Courses.CourseName,
    CoursesTakes.TargetGrade,
    Reports.CurrentGrade,
    Reports.ReportNumber
FROM
    Students
    INNER JOIN CoursesTakes ON Student.StudentID = CoursesTakes.StudentId
    INNER JOIN Courses ON CoursesTakes.CourseID = Courses.CoursesID
    INNER JION Reports ON CoursesTakes.TakeID = Reports.CourseTakeID
WHERE
    Students.StudentID = <yourstudentid>
```

If this doesn't answer the question, then please share some sample data and your desired results so we can have an idea of how your data is structured.

Comment: This looks to have solved the dilemma I was facing. Thank you ever so much!

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

You can try full join to retrieve all records:

```
select 
    Student.*, CourseTake.*, courses.*,Report.* 
from 
    students 
full join  
    CourseTake on Student.ID == CourseTake.StudentID
full join  
    Courses on Courses.id == CourseTake.StudentID
full join  
    Report on CourseTake.ID = CourseTake.Take ID
```